# ImportError: No module named _socket

Tags: python, integration-testing

I am trying to execute a small python code from CPP environment(Visual studio 2008) for test automation.  When I try to add the following code in python script `import socket`. The python code is not getting imported. I am getting the below error.

```
Py_initialize succeededTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Code\MSVC\PythonTest\Proj\Pythoncheck\Debug\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\socket.py", line 47, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: No module named _socket
```

But when i execute the python script alone(`python main.py`), there is no such issue in importing socket. The python script is getting executed fine. Has anyone faced this earlier? Could anyone help me with the solution?

The code `main.py` contains

```
import sys
import socket

print"santhosh"

def startmain():

    while True:
        time.sleep(5000)


pingcount = 0
print "InstartMain"
```

Regards,
Santhosh

Answer (score 2):

The environment where you are launching python might not be the same as the environment where you are launching your CPP program. Try setting [PYTHONHOME](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHOME)

[I know this won't help the original poster, but I ran into this issue trying to use pythonnet from C# in 2018]

Comment: this was a super useful comment :) I think this is what happens when you have a mismatch with the compiler python (or ironpython or maya or whatever) was built with and extensions you may have gotten externally (like pythonnet)